# BeautifulSoup code to Click a Link on a site and then Copy/Paste All Text On Screen to Raw Text File

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, text-files

Hey StackExchange I need some help finalizing a small piece of Python code that I am running on a BeagleBoneBlack through the Linux shell. This is the first of two scripts which saves some raw data to a text file from PSKReporter.info. I've already completed the second parsing script that will use this data, but now want the raw data pull to be in Python as well!

I've experimented in the past using BeautifulSoup as you can see below in my code, but I don't know if it will be able to do the functionality I'm looking for. In particular I don't know how to interact (click) on links to display more data. The most I've done with BeautifulSoup in the past is to search for things like bold tags and then extract pieces of displayed data from them.

Maybe I will need some other packages/functions, but maybe someone can teach me something new about BeautifulSoup too!

**All I want the Python code to do is:**

1. Go to this link https://pskreporter.info/pskmap.html?preset&callsign=en71&what=grid&mode=FT8&band=12000000-16000000&timerange=900&distunit=miles&mapCenter=35.71878123231818,14.756871723642343,2.292836140088628

*Note: The settings should already be set by the link for example, 20m, signals, sent/rcvd by, grid square, EN71, using FT8, over the last 15 minutes.*

2. Click on the hyperlink for "(show logbook)" if it exists. If it doesn't exist, we can just exit and be done. Part of this is working in the below code, at least verifying that "(show logbook)" exists by checking "if str(soup).find("logbook") != -1". This step is the part I'm most unsure about, I've never done "clicking" or interacting inside BeautifulSoup before, just text extraction for later parsing. Can we even get this table to display without having a GUI and Web Browser to interact with the link? What really trips me up is that on the BBB, I'm running this Python code from the Linux shell, there is no link to click on, and there would be nothing actually "displayed", but I imagine this is still possible.
3. Perform a "Ctrl-A" then "Ctrl-C" like command to copy the whole screen of raw text.
4. Have this get stored into a variable or just print it to a raw text file. If you have it stored, I can write it to a .txt file on my own just fine.

Output .txt file example is shown below underneath the code template I've started. I've already got the Python code completed that will take this raw text file, find the first row of data after "Txmtr    Rcvr    Band    Mode    Distance    Time (UTC)", store all the data into individual arrays, do custom parsing and statistics, and text message me under certain conditions that it finds! The code works great and I'd been using it last summer to notify me of conditions when the 6m magic band opened up so I could get on the radio and make some contacts!

My Dad was previously using some AutoHotkey script on a Windows machine to do the initial raw data pull and was sending the raw data to me over FTP to my BeagleBoneBlack. On the BBB I was then using Python to do the rest of the parsing without needing a GUI. His code stopped working and I figured that we could improve upon it by having it all on the BBB instead, however I'm struggling to wrap my head around what is likely a simple step in clicking and copying all the data!

Ignore the odd infinite loop which breaks out after just one iteration. I stole this from some other code I had laying around!

Thank you so much in advance. I've been a long time lurker, but finally decided to make an account and post since I would really like this code working again!

**Bare Bones Pseudocode I've got right now (does work to find if the clickable link is there):**

```
# Import requests (to download the page)
import requests
# Import BeautifulSoup (to parse what we download)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('Setup complete.')

# while this is true (it is true by default),
while True:
    print('This is the beginning of the program. Checking PSKReporter.')
    # set the url
    url = "https://pskreporter.info/pskmap.html?preset&callsign=en71&what=grid&mode=FT8&band=12000000-16000000&timerange=900&distunit=miles&mapCenter=35.71878123231818,14.756871723642343,2.292836140088628"
    # set the headers like we are a browser,
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    # download the homepage
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # parse the downloaded homepage and grab all text, then,
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    
    # if the result is NOT equal to -1, then it found it!
    if str(soup).find("logbook") != -1: 
        print('Found (show logbook), clicking link now')
        #click code here
        
        
        print('Saving Raw Data to "PSKDataFile.txt"')
        #copy and paste all data to raw .txt file here     
        
        
        #break to leave infinite while loop
        break

            
    # but if the word "logbook" didn't appear
    else: #must have been -1
        print('Didnt find the logbook. Try another data search with a different band, different grid square, etc..')
      
            #break to leave the infinite while loop
        break
```

**Example of raw .txt data file:**

```
On 
20m
, show 
signals
 
sent/rcvd by
 
grid square
 
en71
 using 
FT8
 over the last 
15 minutes
  Display options Permalink
Automatic refresh in 4 minutes. Small markers are the 128 transmitters (show logbook) heard at EN71.
There are 793 active FT8 monitors on 20m. Show all FT8 on all bands. Show all on all bands. Legend

Download (ADIF) last 24 hours, last week
Txmtr   Rcvr    Band    Mode    Distance    Time (UTC)
W7FRD   KD9ROL  20m FT8 1360 miles  00:13:27
KF0FSJ  N9AJD   20m FT8 952 miles   00:13:12
N5VJV   KD9ROL  20m FT8 829 miles   00:13:11
KF0FSJ  KD9ROL  20m FT8 957 miles   00:13:11
KC5HXK  KD9ROL  20m FT8 1000 miles  00:13:11
PY2RFL  KD9ROL  20m FT8 4943 miles  00:13:11
LU8LTT  AA9DU   20m FT8 5024 miles  00:12:57
KJ7RGW  AA9DU   20m FT8 1833 miles  00:12:57
KC0FGX  AA9DU   20m FT8 408 miles   00:12:57
W9BFP   AA9DU   20m FT8 1862 miles  00:12:57
VE2FVV  AA9DU   20m FT8 997 miles   00:12:27
K0CAH   KD9ROL  20m FT8 1045 miles  00:12:26
KB5GA   N9AJD   20m FT8 823 miles   00:12:26
KD9ROL  AA7NM   20m FT8 1889 miles  00:12:15
KD9ROL  KD1ELK  20m FT8 1564 miles  00:12:13
WI0R    N9AJD   20m FT8 1037 miles  23:58:41
KD5MZV  KB8CBY  20m FT8 824 miles   23:58:41
KD5MZV  AA9DU   20m FT8 761 miles   23:58:41
Statistics — Comments to Philip Gladstone — Online discussions — Reception records: 25,686,714,752 — Hosting by Fast Serv Networks, LLC
PSKREPORTER.INFO
```

Comment: The issue is not BeautifulSoup.  The issue is that `requests` does not get a live connection.  It fetches the raw HTML of the page.  It does not execute any Javascript.  If you can generate static HTMLs to simulate fetching the next pages, that's fine.   Otherwise, you will have to switch to Selenium, where you are driving an actual browser.

Comment: I had a thought something like that was going on since I had figured everything was just getting a raw HTML and it was just non-interactive text at that point. I'm looking into installing Selenium and a Firefox driver now. Hopefully I can get that to work shortly and start testing its ability to open the page and click! Looks like there might be some code such as this that I'm looking for:

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Logbook')
link.click()

Comment: I've been trying to get Selenium and a WebDriver (Firefox/Chrome) to install but have been having limited success. I think I've got all the PATH situation figured out for Firefox, as I can type "firefox" anywhere and I get a runtime error "Exec format error". This is the same error I ultimately get when I run my Python code when it gets to the point of using Geckodriver to open Firefox. A functioning Firefox on my BBB 32 bit would be a good start. Chrome is no longer supported on 32 bit. Switching to RaspBerry Pi 3 (64 bit) may be my only option to get Selenium working for this method.

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded via JavaScript, so you can use `requests`/`re`/`json` module to parse it. For example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = "https://pskreporter.info/cgi-bin/pskquery5.pl"


query = {
    "encap": "1",
    "callback": "doNothing",
    "statistics": "1",
    "noactive": "1",
    "nolocator": "1",
    "flowStartSeconds": "-900",
    "frange": "12000000-16000000",
    "mode": "FT8",
    "modify": "grid",
    "callsign": "en71",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, params=query).content, "html.parser")
d = re.search(r"doNothing\((.*)\);", soup.js.contents[0], flags=re.S).group(1)
d = json.loads(d)

# pretty print
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
...

    "time2-activeReceivers-cache": 0.005166,
    "activeReceiver": [
        {
            "callsign": "8P6PE",
            "locator": "GK03fd",
            "frequency": 14075582,
            "region": "Saint George",
            "DXCC": "Barbados",
            "decoderSoftware": "JTDX v2.2.158 3c64ff",
            "mode": "FT8"
        },
        {
            "callsign": "K7IIJ",
            "locator": "CN85pm21tv",
            "frequency": 14075222,
            "region": "Oregon",
            "DXCC": "United States",
            "decoderSoftware": "WSJT-X v2.5.2 68dc11",
            "mode": "FT8"
        },

...
```

Comment: This looks like almost exactly what I need Andrej and gives me some more concepts to think about! I like how you got away from the permalink and showed that we can actually interact with the pskquery to change what data we want to see.

Do you know what parameters to modify in the re.search to get extract single sections? You've got part of the printed output for the section "activeReceiver", but there are others such as "receptionReport", "senderSearch", etc.

This is so close to being able to hone in on the most relevant sections, and then parsing the data will be a piece of cake!

Comment: In the worst case if I can't get the json to filter down a little bit more, it looks like the "(show logbook)" hyperlink info I wanted from the original post is in the "receptionReport", which is the last thing printed. 

That shouldn't be too bad to parse down to this point and start extracting the data I want as it is clearly labelled with nice names. 

The UTC time for flowStartSeconds is interestingly in Unix epoch time! It doesn't have the distance here, but that can be calculated with Grid Squares and is something my Dad has been fascinated with different algorithms on lately!